# If you fork() and the forked (child) process exits are all the VM pages still marked COW in the parent?

Tags: c, linux, fork, virtual-memory

On Linux, if you fork() and the forked (child) process exits are all the virtual memory pages still marked as copy-on-write in the parent?

I think the pages will stay marked as COW as anything else would probably be prohibitively expensive to implement, probably requiring per-page ref counts and other expensive book-keeping. But I was wondering the other day, if I fork a process to execute some code in a "stable snapshot" of the current process. What happens when the child process exits? Do all the memory pages in the parent stay marked as copy-on-write? That means that forking in a process with a lot of virtual memory (e.g. 128GB+) only to execute some code for a few minutes would cause lingering performance degradation in the parent process, for hours or even days afterward (not to mention the fork call itself which would not be cheap.)

I'm just curious as to what the actual behavior is on Linux (and I have no idea how I could test it.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should use `posix_spawn`, not `fork`, to run external programs.

Comment: IIRC, COW is set on *both* the parent and child pages. The first one to come gets the pagefault and the page is cloned (and neither of the cloned pages have the COW set anymore) BTW: you could look at teh source. It is open source, you know...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from the copy-on-write bit there is also a reference count in the page table. So when a child forks, all non-private pages in the parentent are marked COW, and the reference count is incremented.

Then while the child process is running, and the parent writes a page, it will get a page fault, and the page is copied like you would expect, and reference count is decreased. When the child exits, it decreases all its page references with one, and the pages with reference count zero are thrown away.

Now when the parent writes a page that has the COW-bit set, and a reference count of one, the COW-bit is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel marks all of the shared pages as write-protected, thus resulting in an exception if either tries to modify one. The duplicate is created, and is marked as writable (thus no more exceptions), while the original remains write-protected.

If the original is written to, another exception occurs, but the kernel will see that the page isn't shared by any other process, and so will mark that one as writeable too. When a process terminates, all of its pages are released, and so the kernel will effectively remove the COW status from every page in the parent when it's modified.